# Qualified name is not allowed in C++, already compiling in C++ 17

Tags: c++, class, c++17, declaration, member

I'm trying to follow the Zombie Arena project in Beginning C++ Game Programming by John Horton.
However, Pickup.h is giving me problems.

```
class Pickup
{
private:
    //Start value for health pickups
    const int HEALTH_START_VALUE = 50;
    const int AMMO_START_VALUE = 12;
    const int START_WAIT_TIME = 10;
    const int START_SECONDS_TO_LIVE = 5;

    // The sprite that represents this pickup
    Sprite m_Sprite;

    // The arena it exists in
    IntRect m_Arena;

    // How much is this pickup worth?
    int m_Value;

    // What type of pickup is this? 
    // 1 = health, 2 = ammo
    int m_Type;

    // Handle spawning and disappearing
    bool m_Spawned;
    float m_SecondsSinceSpawn;
    float m_SecondsSinceDeSpawn;
    float m_SecondsToLive;
    float m_SecondsToWait;

    // Public prototypes go here
public:

    Pickup::Pickup(int type);

    // Prepare a new pickup
    void setArena(IntRect arena);

    void spawn();

    // Check the position of a pickup
    FloatRect getPosition();

    // Get the sprite for drawing
    Sprite getSprite();

    // Let the pickup update itself each frame
    void update(float elapsedTime);

    // Is this pickup currently spawned?
    bool isSpawned();

    // Get the goodness from the pickup
    int gotIt();

    // Upgrade the value of each pickup
    void upgrade();

};
```

When I try to compile the program, I get an illegal qualified name in member declaration error from `Pickup::Pickup(int type)`. What could be wrong? I've tried to debug this with no success. Please help. I'm already compiling in C++ 17.

Comment: I'd change     `Pickup::Pickup(int type);` to    `Pickup(int type);` first, this seems to be the problem

Comment: @alagner And why? If you explain that you have a nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this declaration of the constructor

```
Pickup::Pickup(int type);
```

write

```
Pickup(int type);
```

The qualified name of the constructor declaration is not correct though as far as I know some compilers like MS VS allow such declarations.

You may use a qualified name of a member function in its definition outside the class definition.

Comment: That introduces 15 unresolved external symbol errors. I'd add those, but that'd take up too much space.

Comment: @JoelSeng I have not understood what youmean.

Comment: Edited my comment.

Comment: @JoelSeng The presented by you code has nothing common with your statement.  You should ask a new question about your errors that occurred in some other context.

Comment: [pastebin dump of the errors I get](https://pastebin.com/dKCtXn5x)

Comment: @JoelSeng It means that the linker does not see the definitions. As II said it is another question.